# My chatbot button replies are triggering "away" messages on the page

Tags: facebook-messenger

I have a chatbot that has a simple flow where the user replies to the bot with the buttons on the message that bot sends.

I noticed that when a user clicks on these buttons, it triggers page level "Automated Messages" (such as Away Messages) that is natively set on the page.

Is there a way to disable the automated messages for the user messages triggered via button clicks?

Comment: You should add, what you have done so far, so that we can inspect what's causing it

Comment: I am trying to find a way to programmatically disable the away messages but managed to find zero documentation about "Automated Response" feature on the FB business messenger app.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Get Started button and Greetings using Messenger Profile Api. After that, the away messages will be gone. Here is the for the api: [Messenger Profile Api](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api)